# How to transport input from a website to the same website? html

Tags: html

I created a new website and on this website I created a formular with `<form>`.

Now my question:

If the user fills in the things I asked in my formular and clicks on submit. The answers, which the user filled in, would go to a database, but I want the answers to print on the same website because I don‘t like php.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: if the data stays in the website, how will you use it?

Comment: I want to show the data on this webside like a comment, so that all can see it. I don‘t want to save the data in a database.

Comment: then you must save the data to a database

Comment: I already tried it out with xampp maybe you know that, but I had to write the Code in php, but I am not the best in php 

Comment: you could use a database like Firebase, it's easy to use and doesn't require back-end programming. or you could always learn php ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out